# Correlate svn/trac changest number with hudson build number

Tags: svn, version-control, continuous-integration, hudson, trac

I have a software build that has an internal number from our hudson number. I'm trying to figure out if feature X was included in that build. I know what svn (also shows up in trac if there's a way to do it through trac) changeset this change occurred in. I only store a couple of weeks worth of builds in hudson, so I can't just lookup the build in hudson. Is there a way to determine what changesets were included in which build numbers?

Answer (score 2):

We use hudson with subversion and part of the build process is to automatically add the subversion branch and global revision details to the distribution.  Not sure if Hudson can pick these up and have it appear as some kind of custom field in the web interface.

Comment: Thanks vinnyjames. Do you use a particular plugin to do this or is this a homegrown script to collect that information?

Comment: we use ant to build a java project and there is an ant target to put the revision number and branch in the .jar file's manifest.  then at runtime we pull the version information out of the manifest.